# how to print the arraylist values without bracket ([) and comma (,) and each values in new line in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class extendsArraylist {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> e = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        e.add(1);
        e.add(2);
        e.add(3);
        e.add(4);
        e.add(5);
        e.add(6);
        e.add(7);

        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

If you see the above code it will print [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] rather i want it to print each element in new line without bracket and comma like 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

using the same System.out.println() method , what method should i override to print like this??

Thanks

Comment: You can't; you have to write your own method.

Comment: You should implement your own class (e.g. `MyArrayList`), extend ArrayList and override the `toString` method

Comment: Either like @ParkerHalo mentioned or `System.out.println(e.toString().replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "").replaceAll(", ", System.lineSeparator()));` or any other way depending what you want to achieve.

Comment: This probably isn't what you're question is getting at, but in Java 8 you can "use the same System.out.println()" method and get the desired output by doing this: `e.stream().forEach(System.out::println);` Of course, in this case, you're using the method on the individual elements and not the entire list.

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing this answer since the question might be misunderstood by some:

When an Object-parameter is given in the method `System.out.println(...)` the objects own `toString()` method will be called.

Therefore, if you want to use the same call as you did but with a different outcome you'll have to implement your own `ArrayList` with an overriden `toString()` method:

```
class MyArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T>
{
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (T t : this)
        {
            sb.append(t);
            sb.append(' ');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }    
}
```

Comment: It's probably better if you use a `StringBuilder`, and if you don't add a space after the last element. `ArrayList` allows null values, so `t.toString()` may throw `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Andreas this is just an example implementation. Securing null values + efficient String handling will of course be necessary when implementing a fitting solution

Comment: ThankYou @ParkerHalo your answer is exactly what i was trying to achieve

Comment: **Don't concatenate String objects inside a loop**. Use instead a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @SubOptimal as i already stated in my first comment: This is just an example... The concatenation of Strings is not what is to be shown here, but the Override of the `toString` method. I will change it accordingly anyhow.

Comment: @ParkerHalo But it has the danger that people (not yet familar with Java) will take it as a solution. See the answer from No_One himself. He took it as solution.

Comment: @SubOptimal yes you're right... i've changed my post accordingly and i will probably use StringBuilder more in my future answers to avoid that kind of things ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `for` loop:

```
private void printList(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

**EDIT** after comment: you could also create a String with this method and print it:

```
private String getStringToPrint(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        builder.append(String.valueOf(list.get(i));
        if (i == list.size() -1) {
           builder.append("\n");
        } else {
           builder.append(" ");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

and then print the returned String with `System.out.println()`

Comment: The OP mention `using the same System.out.println() method`. (the reason is still unclear ;-) )

Comment: edited my answer - thanks - didn't really understand that sentence in the question ;-)

Comment: Why are you appending ``\n`` to the buffer? The value of `list.get(i) + " "` is a `String`, so why call `String.valueOf()`? It would be better to call `append(list.get(i)).append(' ')`. You should use `StringBuilder`, not `StringBuffer`. It would be better if you don't add a space after the last element.

Comment: The list contains Integers not Strings - that-s why I added String.valueOf ().... about the Stringbuilder - true I forgot that but the principle stays the same :)

Comment: But `list.get(i) + " "` is a string concatenation, which will automatically convert the element to string before concatenating. The result is *always* a string, no matter the type of the list element, so `String.valueOf()` is not needed at all.

Comment: Ah I forget about that - going to edit my answer at home to avoid buffer and concatenation - also going to corrext the first method which is nonsense

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ParkerHalo

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class extendsArraylist<T> extends ArrayList<T>{

   public static void main (String [] args)
      {
         extendsArraylist<Integer> e =  new extendsArraylist<Integer>();

         e.add(1);
         e.add(2);
         e.add(3);
         e.add(4);
         e.add(5);
         e.add(6);
         e.add(7);

    System.out.println(e);
}

  public String toString()
   {
         String result = "";
         for (T i : this)
           {
             result = result + i.toString() + " " + '\n';   
            }

        return result;      
    }

}
```

this is what i was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

For a Java 8 solution the `toString` method for the subclass of `ArrayList` could be

```
public String toString() {
    return this.stream() // 1
            .map(i -> i.toString()) // 2
            .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())); // 3
}
```

1. get a stream from current list
2. convert the Integer to String
3. join the String values using the line separator on the current machine